# Using JavaScript to hide/remove text from a ul class

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a html web page that has a ul class that contains a user login name and link to a web site and I need to hide or remove the username but maintain the anchor. Is there a way to hide or remove just text from a ul class using JavaScript or a mix of JavaScript and CSS?
Ive experimented with getElementsByTagName and the removeChild method but this is not working because the username and the anchor are within the same ul tag. 
Having completed some investigation the majority of solutions involve an onclick button but this isnt an option.
I would ideally like to use pure JavaScript and not jQuery.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
Thom

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

.navbar-right {
    width : 50%;
    background-color: #ededed;
}

a:active {
    color: red !important;
}
a:hover {
    color: red;
}

/* .list2 {
    display: none;
} */

.list2 a {
    display: block !important;
}

h1 {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px red;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>
<title>Testing</title>
<div class="navbar-right">
<h1>Testing</h1>
<p>This is a test page</p>
<ul class="list1">
<li>list element 1</li>
<li>list element 2</li>
<ul class="list2">
<a href="http://www.google.co.uk" target="_blank">click me</a>
text
</ul>
</ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var removeEl = document.getElementsByTagName('li')[1];
var containerEl = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
containerEl.removeChild(removeEl);
</script>       
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please add an html example to your question?

Comment: Hi Federico. I have added an example of the code I am working with. What I need is for the 'text' inside ul:list2 to be removed but maintain the <a href=""></a>

Comment: For starters the `ul` shouldn't contain an `a` directly, it should be something like `<ul><li><a>...`. Second, you can get the `a` child of the `ul` with `document.queryAll('ul.list2 a')` and set its content to an empty string (if I understood correctly what you want to do) with `.innerHTML= ''`

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You can't have a `<a>` as a child of a `<ul>`. Only a `<li>` can be the child. Also, the `<title>` belongs in the `<head>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably prefer doing something like this

```
var ul = document.querySelector('ul') // First occured ul element
var li = ul.querySelectorAll('li') // All li-elements inside selected ul-element
for ( var item of li ){
  item.textContent = '' // sets all li texts to empty string
  item.remove() // removes all li-elements from dom
  if( item.textContent.indexOf('element 1') > -1 ){
    item.remove() // in this case removes li-element containing text 'list element 1'
  }
  // What ever would be preferred case I would like to do
}
```